# Importing existing certificate from k8s Secret into cert-manager CR Certificate

Tags: cert-manager

Let me start with `Why?`

My cert-manager manages dozens of my certs issued by private ACME CA server. I use them for ingress and egress traffic(mTLS). Now, I have to use certs for some use cases issued by public CA. So cert-manager would not help me with that but could help me with life cycle of these certs (Prometheus metrics to be precise).

Let's say we have some cert in the K8s secret:

```
kubectl create secret generic my-cert \
  --from-file=tls.key=cert.key \
  --from-file=tls.crt=cert.crt
```

Is there a way to create cert-manager `Certificate` from that `Secret`?

Answer (score 1):

According to [Allow upload of external certificates](https://github.com/cert-manager/cert-manager/issues/2507) there is no option to do that right now.